# Postal Code verification in Scheme (Dr. Racket)

Tags: post, scheme, racket, postal-code

I am writing a program in Scheme (Dr. Racket) to verify Canadian postal-codes. The user inputs a postal code and gets a response whether it is valid or not. I got the boolean logic down but I am stumped as to how to actually tell it what the correct format is.

ex. (valid-postal-code? N2L 3G1) => true

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking a domain-specific question (e.g. what's the structure of a valid Canadian postal code), or are you asking how to program it?  It's very hard to tell what the question's about.  Wikipedia discusses the structure of Canadian postal codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada#Components_of_a_postal_code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know if a string has the format of a valid postal code, you can use a regular expression. Canadian postal codes consist of six characters, alternating letters and digits beginning with a letter, with a space embedded between the third and fourth characters. A suitable regular expression is `^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]$`.

if you want to know if a string with a valid format is on the list of postal codes, the easiest solution is a bloom filter. I provide a bloom filter, written in Scheme, at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/04/21/probabilistic-spell-checking/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Canadian postal codes work, but I think what you are asking is that you probably just have a long list of valid codes and need to tell the program that they are ok, and no other codes are.

Using a mutable hash map would be ideal for your purpose: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html